# how to fix bent iron rail

Tags: railing

My contractor hit the iron rail with a bulldozer and dented it pretty bad. Cannot find him now (maybe got Covid).

How to fix this myself? torch it then beat it?

Thanks in advance.  [image]

Comment: Can heat and bang, but might be easier to cut and replace.  Looks like simple 1/4 or 1/2 square tubing/rod, so cut at top and bottom and weld a new piece in.  Trying to straightening it probably will leave it not perfect.

Comment: The bend is likely small enough that heat is not needed. Get a relatively stable point like a parked car and pull it with a "come-along" or chain fall. As commented ,it will be difficult to make it perfect.

Comment: Contractor disappeared, eh? Sounds like he's not willing to take responsibility for the damage he caused. Sad.

Answer (score 3):

**Remove bent post and replace it with this post.**

[image]

By which I mean the one I circled in red.  That post is so close to the main post it serves no structural purpose.  It actually looks kind of crowded.  It is almost like they provided you a spare.  Take out the bent one and put this one in its place.  Easy peasy and you already own a post the right length that is a perfect match for the rest.

If you decide to try this please post image of finished job.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this before replacing the bar.

Just a thought off the top of my head, so it may or may not work.

Clamp the bar between wooden boards.

Then pull to straighten.

The boards will prevent other parts of the bar from bending when you pull on the bar.

[image]